# Is there any efficient way both getting 'max' and 'argmax' with a multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `a` with shape (18,4096,4096).

And I want to do like these:

```py
max_value = np.max(a,0)
index = np.argmax(a,0)
```

`max_value`  and `index` are both array with shape (4096, 4096), and I think calling both `np.max` and `np.argmax` has some useless cost.

And I know if `a` is a 1D array, I can do like this:

```py
index = np.argmax(a,0)
max_value = a[index]
```

But I can't do like this when `a` is a 3D array. Is there any efficient way doing this?

Comment: look at `np.take_along_axis`

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
i, j = np.meshgrid(np.arange(a.shape[1]), np.arange(a.shape[2]), indexing='ij')
max_value = a[index[i,j],i,j]
```

or following @hpaulj's suggestion (~2x faster):

```
max_value  = np.take_along_axis(a, index[None], 0)
```